# Spring JMS Oracle AQ - Specifying Dequeue Options

Tags: spring, jms, oracle-aq

I am using Spring JMS for oracle AQ. How can I specifiy Dequeue options?
I want to specify `consumer` name and `dequeue_mode` options.

Answer (score -1):

Old question but here is an XML configuration example.  The consumer name property is called "messageListener".  I'm not sure what dequeue_mode is... I'd recommend looking at the documentation for the AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer for all of the available properties.

```
<bean id="myBeanId" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="myConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="myTransactionManager"/>
    <property name="destinationName" value="myDestinationName"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="myConsumer"/>
    <property name="concurrency" value="1-50"/>
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="5000"/>
    <property name="idleTaskExecutionLimit" value="10"/>
    <property name="idleConsumerLimit" value="5"/>
    <property name="messageSelector" value="JMSType = 'mySelectorIfNeeded'"/>
    <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_CONSUMER"/>
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"/>
</bean>
```